# How to check whether a checkbox is checked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

first of all thank you for your time i really appreciate it. I am trying to use javascript to recognize if a an html checkbox was checked. Here is a code example of how i imagined it would be.

```
enter code here
var submit = document.getElementById("btn");
var para1 = document.getElementById("p1");
var para2 = document.getElementById("p2");
var para3 = document.getElementById("p3");
var pA = true;
var pB = true;
var pC = true;

function submitForm(){ 
    for(p1 == pA, p1 == onclick){ 

    }
}
```

so obviously thats not going to work but my question is basically is what im trying to do possible with javascript(im sure it is)? And how should i go about it?

Comment: sorry about the weird for loop i just didnt know how else to express it in code so i did that which i know is invalid syntax lol

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
You can check the "checked" property once you have the object of that checkbox.

```
var chbox = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(chbox.checked);  //true if checked,false otherwise
```